# Connecting from android client to server

Tags: android, android-networking

I am trying to send simple text from android as client to a server app in java . The server listens to a specific port (say 3363) and the android client app successfully sends data from the test server ip : 10.0.2.2 to any server port (say in this case 3363) .

But when I try to make it listen to any other IP , it just does not go through. If someone can please help me with this .

Comment: `But when I try to make it listen to any other IP`. You don't have to care about your server listening on a specific ip. The only thing relevant is that the server listens on a specific port. Further it would have made more sense if your problem was 'when i try to connect my client to another ip..'.  Please explain better what you want. And tell if you want to use an emulator or a device.

Answer (score 0):

Possible cause :

1) In the first case, your device and server both are connected to same network, e.g, using same Wi-Fi network, hence working. Later when you change the server IP address, the firewall of network of new IP address in blocking the packets.

Comment: In the second case also my PC and app are on the same computer but I am just trying to connect through an ip of 192.168.0.173 which is my same network other than 10.0.2.2 which is Android's test server ip ... Unfortunately the server java application listens only on port number ... But there is no IP assigned to it ... Maybe that'z the case that there is no server running on that IP .... Well the basic task is to connect an android app to a server running on 192,168.0.173 which has been created in LABVIEW ....

Comment: If the computer, where your emulator is running on, has ip 192.168.0.173 you cannot use that ip in a client app running on the emulator in order to connect to a server running on your computer. You can only use 10.0.2.2 for that.